# angular2 how do I get a different subclass of an `@Injectable` depending on the platform - cordova or browser?

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I want to do something like this to keep my `platform=cordova` code separate from my `platform=browser` code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { File } from 'ionic-native';

declare var window;
@Injectable()
export class ImageSrcService {
  constructor(protected platform: Platform){ 
    if (platform.is('cordova')) {
      // I want an instance of CordovaService
    } else {
      // I want an instance of BrowserService
    }
  }
  getSrc(id: string) : Promise<string> {}
}

export class BrowserService extends ImageSrcService {
  constructor(protected platform: Platform){
    super(platform);
  }
  getSrc(id: string) : Promise<string> {
    const uri = `http://example.com/images/${id}.jpg`;
    return Promise.resolve(uri);
  }
}

export class CordovaService extends ImageSrcService{
  constructor(protected platform: Platform){
    super(platform);
  }
  getSrc(id: string) : Promise<string> {
    // File.checkFile('/images/', `${id}.jpg`)
    const fullPath = `/images/${id}.jpg`;
    return new Promise<string>( (resolve, reject)=>{
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( 
        fullPath
        , (fileEntry) => {
          if (fileEntry.isFile) 
            return resolve( fileEntry.nativeURL );
          reject("File not found");
        });
    });
  }
}
```

How do I use dependency injection to create the right instance based the provided `Platform` value, which is determined at runtime?

Comment: You can create two instance of the service, then using dependency injection useFactory feature you can decide which service you inject. Please refer this for more info: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure the `providers`, you can use a factory. In the factory you can inject the `Platform` and decide based on the that what should be returned as the global instance of `ImageSrcService`. And in all your services, you just inject `ImageSrcService` instead of any concrete implementation

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: ImageSrcService, // token, this is what you inject
    useFactory: (platform: Platform) => {
      // do check and return the one to use
      if (plaform.is('cordova') {
        return CordovaSrcService();
      } else {
        return new BroswerSrcService()
      }
    },
    deps: [ Platform ]
  }
]
```

Not sure what `Platform` is, but this assumes that it is a provider that is available at the time the factory is called.

Comment: This happens in the providers for the `Component` that imports `ImageSrcService`, correct? Not in the providers for the `ImageSrcService` itself.

Comment: The `@NgModule` if it's an application scoped service (only one instance). In the `@Component` if you want each component to get its own instance

Comment: so if it is an application scoped service, I only need to `provide` once at the `@NgModule`, but I still need to `import {ImageSrcService} from "..."` wherever I want to `@Inject` it. correct?